# ProgessBar progressing too quickly with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android

I'm trying to animate a progress bar so that it takes 1 minutes to be filled linearly.

Here is my code:

```
animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progress_bar, "progress", 0, 100);
animator.setDuration(1000 * 60);
animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animator.start();

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="9sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="100"
    android:min="0"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

The progress bar is filled too quickly, in about 20 seconds, instead of 1 min

Comment: Under Developer Options, there is the option Animator duration scale. This may be what is causing your problem.

Comment: Great comment Andrea: my option for animation duration scale was set to 0.5. Please post this as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the animation duration scale set to 0.5 under Android's Developer Options.

There is a **setDurationScale()** method in ValueAnimator class. It is hidden, but
you can call it using reflection, and use it to set duration scale to 1:

```
try {
    ValueAnimator.class.getMethod("setDurationScale", float.class).invoke(null, 1f);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), t.getMessage());
}
```

This will make ObjectAnimator independant from global animator duration scale.

If you need to save the current option value for animation duration scale:

```
// Get duration scale from the global settings.
float durationScale = Settings.Global.getFloat(context.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Under Developer Options, there is the option Animator duration scale. This may be what is causing your problem.

Hope it helps.